# Mock MediaProvider on 8.2

Tags: unit-testing, fakedb

I am using FakeDB trying to mock a media provider.  I get this message when attempting the example shown in the wiki.

**Starting from Sitecore 8.2, the Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider class is marked as obsolete and will be removed in the next major release. Please use new abstract type Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseMediaManager from the Sitecore.Kernel assembly.**

How would this look in 8.2 exactly?  I've tried the following but nothing is returned.

```
 var mediaProvider =
          Substitute.For<BaseMediaManager>();

        mediaProvider
          .GetMediaUrl(target)
          .Returns(expectedUri);

       // act
        var mediaUrl = Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(newID).MediaUrl(template.FieldId);
```

Answer (score 1):

`BaseMediaManager` is an abstract class.

Try using `Sitecore.Resources.Media.DefaultMediaManager` which is derived class of `BaseMediaManager`

[image: JustDecompile view]

I'm using `JustDecompile` to see the class and inheritance chain of Sitecore classes.

Answer (score 1):

The decision to obsolete the switchers was predicted by `SitecoreAuthenticationProvider` which [became obsolete](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/issues/173) in 8.2:

```
/// <summary>SitecoreAuthenticationProvider class</summary>
[Obsolete]
public class SwitchingAuthenticationProvider : AuthenticationProvider
```

There was a wrong dependency on that class which has been fixed in [v1.6.0](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/releases/tag/v1.6.0).
But it looks like it was a premature decision to obsolete the FakeDb classes. All the mentioned Sitecore providers are still valid and work fine (at least for 8.2 versions including Update-4). There is no reason in showing the warning.

The FakeDb switchers have been restored in [v1.7.0](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/releases/tag/v1.7.0).